# Scraping phones and ZIPs URLs from CSV to CSV

Tags: python, csv, url, scrapy, web-crawler

I need to scrape a list of URLs stored in a CSV and export to another CSV. I must make some mistake cause I can't run it. So if anyone can help me, I appreciate.

I'm very new in Python and also unite some codes so I have some issues to identificate where is the problem. I mixed a code that import an CSV and another code that require an string search.

```
    import scrapy
    from scrapy import Spider
    from scrapy import Request
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urllib.parse import urlparse
    import requests
    import pandas as pd
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from urllib.request import urlopen,urlparse, Request,HTTPError
    import re
    import numpy as np
    import csv
    from http.client import BadStatusLine
    import ssl
```

The following is the code that I have so far.

```
    
    phn_1 = []
    zipcode_1 = []
    err_msg_zipcode = []
    err = []
    
    class Spider:
      name = 'spider'
    
        # read csv with just url per line
      with open('urls.csv') as file:
          start_urls = [line.strip() for line in file]
     
      def start_request(self):
          request = Request(url = self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)
          yield request
        
      def parse(self, response):
        
          s = response.body
          soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
          text = soup.get_text()
    
          df2=pd.DataFrame()
    
          phn_1 = []    #store all the extracted Phn numbers in a List
          mail_1 = []    #store all the extracted Zipcode in a List
          for line in df2.iterrows():  # Parse through each url in the list.
              try:
                  try:
                      req1 = Request(row[1]['URL'], headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36'})
                      gcontext = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23) # Bypass SSL certification verification
                      f = urlopen(req1, context=gcontext)
                      url_name = f.geturl() #extract URL name 
                      s = f.read()
                      phone = re.findall(r'\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}', s, re.MULTILINE)
                      zipcode = re.findall(r'(?<=, [A-Z]{2} )\d{5}', s, re.MULTILINE)
    
                      if len(phone) == 0:
                          print("No phone number found.")
                          err_msg_phn = "No phone number found."
                          phn_1.append((url_name, err_msg_phn))
                  
                      else:
                          count = 1
                          for item in phone:
                              phn_1.append((url_name,item))
                              count += 1
                          print(phn_1)
            
                      if len(zipcode) == 0:
                          print("No zipcode found.")
                          err_msg_zipcode = "No zipcode address found."
                          zipcode_1.append((url_name,err_msg_zipcode))
    
                      else:
                          count = 1
                          for item in zipcode:
                              mail_1.append((url_name,item))
                              count += 1
                          print(mail_1)
                   
                  except BadStatusLine: # Catch if invalid url names exist
                      print("could not fetch %s" % url_name)
    
              except urllib3.request.HTTPError as err: # catch HTTP 404 not found error
                  if err == 404:
                      print("Received HTTPError on %s" % url_name)
                
    
    df_p = pd.DataFrame()
    df_m = pd.DataFrame()
    df_final = pd.DataFrame()
    
    df_p = pd.DataFrame(phn_1,columns=['URL','Phone_No']) # Dataframe for url and Phn number
    df_phn = df_p.drop_duplicates(subset=['URL', 'Phone_No'], keep='first') #remove duplicates
    
    df_m = pd.DataFrame(zipcode_1,columns=['URL','Zipcode']) # Dataframe for url and Zipcode
    df_mail = df_m.drop_duplicates(subset=['URL','Zipcode'], keep='first') #remove duplicates
    
    df_final = pd.merge(df_phn,df_mail, on = 'URL', how = 'inner') #Merge two dataframes on the common column
    #df_final.groupby(['URL'], as_index=False)
    df_final.to_csv('result_contact.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
    
    #convert the csv output to json
    with open('result_contact.csv') as f:
         reader = csv.DictReader(f)
         rows = list(reader)
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

One obvious mistake I see is here:

```
  request = Request(url = self.start_urls, callback=self.parse)
```

`url` should be a string, but you are sending a list. If you want to send multiple requests, you need to use a loop. As you are already setting `start_urls` and using the `parse` callback, you do not need to override `start_requests`. The default implementation should take care of it.

You may want to consider setting the `start_urls` in the `__init__` method.